The bound variable does not change after execute() per example #5 PDO Stored Procedures in the PHP Documentation,
I've been doing what I'm about to explain using ASP classic and ASP.Net with MSSQL Server for all that time and it works beautifully!
Please, read carefully. Example #5 comes from here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php
Other "references" to answers to my question either suppose it works (like the second answer in Stored Procedures, MySQL and PHP ) or is different in some fundamental way. It is that example (#5 or the answer in that last link) that DOES NOT WORK as given.
Here below is the simplest example, one of MANY, and connection methods I have tried that utterly fails, just like all the rest. The SP works in MariaDb when Executed, but the data is never returned or at least the variable $value is never updated in PHP. In all examples I've tried, I've been able to verify that the data is reaching the SP and everything works fine there.
According to all the examples I have found (particularly #5 above), this should work, but not for me. What could possibly be the problem? I'm just not seeing or finding it. I must be lacking knowledge somewhere.
config.php
<?php

$dsn = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=rolodex;charset=utf8mb4";

$options = [
  PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false, // Disable emulation mode for "real" prepared statements
  PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION, // Disable errors in the form of exceptions
  PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC, // Make the default fetch be an associative array
];

try {
  $pdo = new PDO($dsn, "dbuser", "dbuserpassword", $options);
}
catch (Exception $e) {
  error_log($e->getMessage());
  exit('Something bad happened');
}

?>

pdocontacts.php
<?php

// Include the database connection file
include_once("config.php");

// PHP class 
class Contact {
      public $id;
      public $name;
      public $age;
      public $email;
}

// Fetch contacts (in descending order)
$contacts = $pdo->query( "SELECT * FROM contacts ORDER BY id DESC")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'Contact'); // This returns an array of data inserted.
var_dump($contacts);

$stmt = $pdo->prepare("CALL sp_takes_string_returns_string(?)");
$value = 'hello'; // THIS VALUE IS SET HERE AND SHOULD CHANGE
$stmt->bindParam(1, $value, PDO::PARAM_STR|PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT, 4000); 

// call the stored procedure
$stmt->execute(); // THIS IS SUPPOSED TO CHANGE THE BOUND VAR $value

print "procedure returned $value<br>"; // SAME AS IT WAS SET!

?>

The MariaDb Stored Procedure sp_takes_string_returns_string:
// THIS WORKS! //
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_takes_string_returns_string`(INOUT `astr` VARCHAR(100))
BEGIN
    INSERT contacts (name, age, email) VALUES (astr, 1, 'im@mywittsend.com');
    SELECT REVERSE(astr) INTO astr;
END$$
DELIMITER ;

pdocontacts.php output:
array(5) { \[0\]=\> object(Contact)#3 (4) { \["id"\]=\> int(5) \["name"\]=\> string(5) "hello"
\["age"\]=\> int(1) \["email"\]=\> string(15) "im@mywittsend.com" } \[1\]=\> object(Contact)#4 (4)
{ \["id"\]=\> int(4) \["name"\]=\> string(5) "hello" \["age"\]=\> int(1) \["email"\]=\> string(15)
"im@mywittsend.com" } \[2\]=\> object(Contact)#5 (4) { \["id"\]=\> int(3) \["name"\]=\> string(5)
"hello" \["age"\]=\> int(1) \["email"\]=\> string(15) "im@mywittsend.com" } \[3\]=\>
object(Contact)#6 (4) { \["id"\]=\> int(2) \["name"\]=\> string(5) "hello" \["age"\]=\> int(1)
\["email"\]=\> string(15) "im@mywittsend.com" } \[4\]=\> object(Contact)#7 (4) { \["id"\]=\> int(1)
\["name"\]=\> string(5) "hello" \["age"\]=\> int(1) \["email"\]=\> string(15) "im@mywittsend.com" }
}
procedure returned hello

I even swapped the insert and reverse to show that the reverse is working.
SELECT REVERSE(astr) INTO astr;
INSERT contacts (name, age, email) VALUES (astr, 1, 'im@wittsend.com');

After a couple executions of the page:
array(7) { [0]=> object(Contact)#3 (4) { ["id"]=> int(7) ["name"]=> string(5) "olleh"
["age"]=> int(1) ["email"]=> string(15) "im@wittsend.com" } [1]=> object(Contact)#4 (4) {
["id"]=>...
**procedure returned hello**

You can see that 'hello' or 'olleh' is being inserted into contacts as the name.
What flag or whatever am I missing???

As far as I know it's not supported with PDO_MYSQL

So you're essentially trying to pass a PHP variable by reference into a mariadb stored procedure? I would suggest not doing that and just having the stored procedure return the data that it returns or, if the SP cannot be modified, create a wrapper SP for that does that.

Dharman, it is in the PHP PDO documentation. Is the documentation lacking? Where is one supposed to learn that a feature is just kidding?

Sammitch, That is the gist of bindParam, you pass a variable by reference. That is what it does. If you want to use a literal you use bindValue. The point is the code does not do what it says it is supposed to. I figure I'm missing something else that isn't stated in the documentation. This feature, if it worked, would make my life even simpler than the ASP hoops gave me.

It's worth noting that PDO has theoretical support for things, but the actual implementation and support for each feature depends on it being implemented in the database-specific PDO driver being used, and of course support for it in the target DBMS as well. In a couple of other places in the docs it does mention where support for things isn't available in certain drivers, and indeed if you look just above in example 4 about output parameters, it does indeed say "If the database driver supports it". The core PDO documentation isn't DBMS-specific, so does not enumerate exactly who supports what

But if we look in the driver-specific documentation: https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php we actually do see written: _"Note:
The MySQL driver does not properly support PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT via PDOStatement::bindParam(); while such parameters can be used, they are not updated (i.e. the actual output is ignored)."_. So it is documented, in fact.

ADyson - THANK YOU! That is the bit I was missing. And the answer to why something documented doesn't work. I didn't know that was done in this language. I'd expect it to be noted at the feature page that it didn't work. And I wasn't looking for anything to do with MySQL, since I'm using MariaDb. I don't know I would have ever found that. This wasn't clear from anything else I found. Your comment should be an answer so I can accept it.

The question is currently closed as a duplicate so I can't answer it. The reason it's not documented on the feature page is because PDO is written to be an interface to lots of different databases. But not all databases can support every feature, so then each database-specific PDO driver documents anything it's unable to provide. MariaDB started off as a fork of MySQL, they use the same protocol and are still sufficiently similar that nobody yet has thought it necessary to write a separate driver for it. (If you were doing this in asp.net you'd also use the mysql connector to access mariadb)
